# Почему нет варианта maven, при создании нового проекта и как его добавить?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему нет варианта maven, при создании нового проекта и как его добавить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зайди в `File -> Settings... -> Plugins` и нажми галочку у чекбокса с Maven. Затем перезагрузи IDE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После перезагрузки должен появиться в списке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]